# Why below code cannot output Hello World?

Tags: linux, multithreading, cpu-cache

Why below code cannot output Hello World! Is it related to CPU cache? But I think the CPU should guarantee the cache consistency, right? Should thread_fun refresh the cache from memory after thread_fun2 modify the value. I know atomic could resolve this issue, But I don't know why below code doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
int a = 4;

void thread_fun() {
    while(a!=3) {

    }
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}
void thread_fun2() {
    a=3;
    printf("Set!\n");
}


int main()  {
    auto tid=std::thread(thread_fun);
    auto tid2=std::thread(thread_fun2);
    tid.join();
    tid2.join();
}
```

Build Options:

```
g++ -o multi multi.cc -O3 -std=c++11 -lpthread
```

Below is gdb output

```
(gdb) disass thread_fun
Dump of assembler code for function _Z10thread_funv:
   0x0000000000400af0 <+0>:     cmpl   $0x3,0x201599(%rip)        # 0x602090 <a>
   0x0000000000400af7 <+7>:     je     0x400b00 <_Z10thread_funv+16>
   0x0000000000400af9 <+9>:     jmp    0x400af9 <_Z10thread_funv+9>
   0x0000000000400afb <+11>:    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000400b00 <+16>:    mov    $0x401090,%edi
   0x0000000000400b05 <+21>:    jmpq   0x4008f0 <puts@plt>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disass thread_fun2
Dump of assembler code for function _Z11thread_fun2v:
   0x0000000000400b10 <+0>:     mov    $0x40109d,%edi
   0x0000000000400b15 <+5>:     movl   $0x3,0x201571(%rip)        # 0x602090 <a>
   0x0000000000400b1f <+15>:    jmpq   0x4008f0 <puts@plt>
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Test output

```
[root@centos-test tmp]# ./multi 
Set!
^C
[root@centos-test tmp]# ./multi 
Set!
^C
[root@centos-test tmp]# ./multi 
Set!
^C
[root@centos-test tmp]# ./multi 
Set!
^C
[root@centos-test tmp]# ./multi 
Set!
^C
```

UPDATE:
   thanks everybody, Now I found actually this issue was caused by compiler.

```
(gdb) disass thread_fun
Dump of assembler code for function _Z10thread_funv:
   0x0000000000400af0 <+0>:     cmpl   $0x3,0x201599(%rip)        # 0x602090 <a>
   0x0000000000400af7 <+7>:     je     0x400b00 <_Z10thread_funv+16>
   0x0000000000400af9 <+9>:     jmp    0x400af9 <_Z10thread_funv+9>  ###jump to itself
   0x0000000000400afb <+11>:    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000400b00 <+16>:    mov    $0x401090,%edi
   0x0000000000400b05 <+21>:    jmpq   0x4008f0 <puts@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

It seems the compiler treated it as a single thread application.

Comment: Try building without -O3 and it'll work. It's because your code is buggy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the standard says the compilers are allowed to optimise your code code AS-IF it was data race free (not a direct quote!).

So when it analyse

```
while(a!=3) {

}
```

It sees it needs to check `a!=3` and nothing is happening until next time the loop is repeated, hence no need to check `a` again as it couldn't have changed.

So changing the type of a to an `std::atomic<int>` will force it to examine the value of `a` again and the loop should work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

The formal explanation is that you are not allowed to read/write access a non-atomic variable in multiple threads. It's called a data-race and it triggers undefined behavior.

Because it is not allowed, the compiler is not required to commit a store to `a` to the L1-cache and therefore it remains invisible to other threads. You are seeing the effect of this in your code when you compile with `-O3` optimization.

As you said, the solution is to change `a` to a `std::atomic<int>` (a data-race-free type) and you are all set.

Comment: should the committing to cache is determined by CPU not compiler? i did see there is a `movl   $0x3,0x201571(%rip)` in thread_fun2. This mov will trigger an updating in cache, right?

Comment: Whether a store is committed to cache or remains inside a CPU register depends on the instructions. And the instructions are emitted by the compiler. So, at the end, it's the compiler that decides how a store is treated.

Comment: You are right, the store should update the cache, but the receiving thread is not required to read from the cache. That's the thing with 'undefined behavior', it's sometimes difficult to reason about

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is a typical use case for std::[condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
int a = 4;

void thread_fun() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    cv.wait(lk, []{return a == 3;});
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}

void thread_fun2() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    a = 3;
    printf("Set!\n");
}

int main()  {
    auto tid=std::thread(thread_fun);
    auto tid2=std::thread(thread_fun2);
    tid.join();
    tid2.join();
}
```

Note the use of lock_guard and unique_lock helps to synchronize between thread1 and thread2 using the mutex m.

Comment: Although you do not answer the question, the suggestion is valid (upvote)